# Reactive MySQL configuration with quarkus

Tags: mysql, reactive, quarkus

Can someone help with configuring MySQL reactive client with the quarkus? What are the plugins/extension I need for it? And what are the minimum exact application properties to be configured for the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add single dependency, for mysql it would be:

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-mysql-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then, in application properties you need to specify datasource info, minimal setup for me was:

```
quarkus.datasource.url=vertx-reactive:mysql://localhost:3306/{database}
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.password=root
```

Replace host, port, database and credentials as you need

Last part is to use `MySQLPool`, just inject it in some bean:

```java
@Inject
MySQLPool pool;
```

You can try my [example repo](https://github.com/dmi3coder/reactive-database-client) as well

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I also had the same configuration. I am getting following error:
Caused by: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to determine the driver for default datasource

Comment: Which version of quarkus do you have? 1.3.0? Be sure to put `vertx-reactive:` in front of `quarkus.datasource.url` value instead of jdbc if you copying it from other jdbc string

Comment: I am using 1.3.1 and yeah the 'vertx-reactive' prefix is there